# How to use postman to send a request to timekit api

Tags: rest, curl, postman

I don't know much about how to use an API, and I am just trying to get a basic understanding so I can use the Timekit.io API in a JS app I am going to build, so to start I though I should try and use postman to learn how to send a request. In the Timekit documentation for finding a time from a resource ie: a persons calendar they say to use this curl command.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.timekit.io/v2/findtime \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --user :live_api_key_7nzvc7wsBQQISLeFSVhROys9V1bUJ1z7 \
  --data '{
  "resource_ids": ["78a4d873-2a68-41c6-bdd4-c0ca5b35efd3"],
  "filters": { "or": [
    {"specific_day_and_time":{"day":"Monday","start":9,"end":13}},
    {"specific_day_and_time":{"day":"Wednesday","start":10,"end": 16}}
  ]},
  "future": "2 days",
  "length": "30 minutes"
}'
```

I am trying to figure out what I put into postman itself so I get the correct Json values. So far I have selected a `POST` request with the url `https://api.timekit.io/v2/findtime` and a `header` with the key `Content-Type` and value `application/json` I have no idea where to put the `user,data,rsource_ids,filters,future & length` Here is a screenshot of my post man setup.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `--user` sets the authentication. If an authentication type is not specified, then it will default to [Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). In Postman, click the "Authentication" tab and from the "Type" dropdown, select "Basic Auth". You can then input the username and password into the appropriate fields. With the `--user` flag, the value should be `<username>:<password>`. So your case, there is no username specified, so I guess you don't need to input it, just use the api key for the password.
- `--data` is the JSON request body. You can input this entire value (within the single quotes `'`) into the "Body" tab. Select the "Body" tab, and within the tab, select the "raw" radio button, and from the dropdown to the right, select "JSON (application/json)". Now just put the entire JSON into the text area.

  ```
  {
    "resource_ids": ["78a4d873-2a68-41c6-bdd4-c0ca5b35efd3"],
    "filters": {
      "or": [
        { "specific_day_and_time":{ "day":"Monday", "start":9, "end":13 } },
        { "specific_day_and_time":{ "day":"Wednesday", "start":10, "end": 16 } }
      ]
    },
    "future": "2 days",
    "length": "30 minutes"
  }
  ```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This isn't actually working for me, I am getting Invalid credentials am I not supposed to put the api_key somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You could just drop the curl request straight into Postman via the `Import` feature, this would populate the whole request in the application for you.

In the top left of the application UI, select the `Import` button and then select the 'raw' text option (it’s the last one) - paste the curl request text into the text box. Once imported, that should do the rest for you, if it’s a valid format.